Exporting polygons to existing database in QGIS
I have exported a shp polygon file in QGIS to a table in pgAdmin. Now I have more polygons in QGIS that I want to export to the same table in pgAdmin. This means that I want to add the new polygons to the existing table. Is there a way to do this?

I would use the data in PostGIS and connect to the database usng QGIS. Others have done the db>shp>db route https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104581/how-to-update-postgis-layer-from-shapefile-in-qgis

Point of information: No table is ever "in pgAdmin". pgAdmin is a database client application. The data is in the RDBMS, PostgreSQL (PostGIS is the database extension which provides "Simple Types and Functions" implementation of the geometry and geography datatypes inside of PostgreSQL). Yes, there is a way to do this (you've already done it). It is advised to load all your data in one go, since loading one row at a time is very inefficient.

Easiest way: drag and drop
Simply drag-and-drop the layers to the database table (see screenshot below):

In the Browser Panel, create a new connection (or open an existing one) to your PostGIS database.
In the Layers Panel, select the layer(s) you want to import into PostGIS table.
Drag and drop the Layers from step 2 to the table from step 1.


More sophisticated: DB Manager
Alternatively, you could also activate the core plugin DB Manager and connect there to the PostGIS database. There, you have a menu item Import Layer/File... to import vector layers you have in your QGIS project to PostGIS. You also have an SQL window to make a query there to import, delete, change etc. your database.

